# Locate an element in selenium using text inside h2 tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select the following h2 element using the text in selenium -

```html
   

<h2>
   <span id="presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt95"><a id="presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt95:j_idt97" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget chekChartLink" aria-label="Technical Information" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt95:j_idt97',process:'presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt95:j_idt97',update:'chekChartForm',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){chekChartWidget.show();}});return false;" title="Technical Information">
   <span class="icon-border icon-large icon-wrench"></span></a>
   </span>Water Pump
   <div id="presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt101" class="ui-datalist ui-widget service-tsbs">
  <div id="presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt101_content" class="ui-datalist-content ui-widget-content"></div>
   </div>
   <script id="presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt101_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('DataList','widget_presentations_0_categoryHeaderForm_j_idt101',{id:'presentations:0:categoryHeaderForm:j_idt101'});</script>
</h2>
```

I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Water Pump')]"));
```

but get:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 4):

You should either specify the index of child text node which should contain required substring, e.g. `//h2[contains(text()[2], 'Water Pump')]` or try to select header by *text that is part of its string representation*:

```
//h2[contains(., 'Water Pump')]
```

Comment: good answer... but he is looking for a different element that is a sibling to `h2` if I understood him correctly

Comment: @MosheSlavin , I saw only *"select the following h2 element"*, so `h2` itself... If OP need to select *any* following sibling, then it might be `//h2[contains(., 'Water Pump')]/following-sibling::*` or for *specific* following sibling - `//h2[contains(., 'Water Pump')]/following-sibling::TAG_NAME`

Comment: @Andersson, I need what you suggested and then I can figure it out. But your solution isn't working and I got - `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //h2[contains(., 'Water Pump')]`

Comment: @apun , XPath is correct for provided HTML sample. If you're still getting `NoSuchElementException` you might need to apply [Explicit/Implicit wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: No, its not an wait issue.

Comment: @apun , maybe it is located inside an iframe?

Comment: No, its not. So if I use the xpath till h2 without text and do a getText on it, it returns the text contained inside h2. Just that I need to identify h2 with text. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @apun , is it a public page? can you share URL?

Comment: I am sorry, its not public. Anyways, I appreciate you trying out to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wild card `*` and `following-sibling::` in the xpath like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text()[2], 'Water Pump')]/following-sibling::*"));
```

Here is an example in [this link](http://xpather.com/e3tpG2kc).

Hope this helps you!

P.s.

the credit is to @Anderson for the XPath... see in the comments

Comment: No its not working. And By the approach I mentioned above in my question, if I do `getText()`, I see that test returned by simply using `h2`. But I need text as I need to find another element.

Comment: @apun I changed the answer to ues: `parent::` to reach the element

Comment: What do you mean by `@yourTag`? I thought `h2` is a tag in itself. Modified HTML as you asked. And I can't use `@id` as that's dynamic and some other element may have it next time.

Comment: @apun Sorry I meant attribute... like `id`... now that you have updated the HTML can you tell me which element you want? the one above `"Water Pump"`?

Comment: No, its some other sibling in the hierarchy. I can't paste the whole code here as it will be too big. But if I could select this `h2` having this text, I can select the sibling as well

Comment: @apun just to be clear... you are looking for a sibling element of `h2`? If so just grab the `h2` with the text and use `following-sibling::` in the xpath... if you do add more of the HTML for the actual element you are looking for I will understand better...

Comment: That's what my question is - I am unable to grab the h2 tag with text. Isn't it?