# Selenium Python: Unable to find h2 element using xpath or css (with and without text)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a clickable (I think - see code below) h2 element.

Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<div class="center-block flex-y v-center h-fill">
    <div class="flex-y v-center h-start">
        <h2 class="section-name ng-binding" ng-attr-tabindex="{{ appbar.service.disableProductSectionClick ? -1 : 0 }}" ng-click="appbar.clickProductSection()" ng-keydown="appbar.clickProductSection($event)" ng-class="{ 'inactive': appbar.service.disableProductSectionClick || !appbar.homeState }" tabindex="0">Password Safe</h2>
        <app-bar-breadcrumbs class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <ul class="flex-x h-start v-center">
                <!-- ngRepeat: link in crumbs.service.list track by $index -->.
                <li ng-repeat="link in crumbs.service.list track by $index" ng-click="crumbs.navTo($index)" ng-keydown="crumbs.navTo($index, $event)" data-name="Requests" data-collapse="false" ng-attr-tabindex="{{ (crumbs.service.list.length === $index + 1 || link.method == 'stateless') ? '-1' : '0' }}" ng-hide="crumbs.service.hidden.indexOf($index) > -1" ng-class="{ 'stateless': link.method == 'stateless' }" class="flex-x static h-start v-center ng-binding ng-scope" tabindex="-1">
                </li>
                <!-- end ngRepeat: link in crumbs.service.list track by $index -->
            </ul>
        </app-bar-breadcrumbs>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to find the h2 element using xpath, sometimes with text. Code always returns TimeOutException. The element is not inside a frame but it is inside a bt-app-bar.

1. Full xpath

```
homepage_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/bt-app-chrome/bt-app-bar/div[2]/div[3]/div/h2')))
```

2. xpath with tail and contains

```
homepage_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Password Safe")]')))
```

3. xpath with text

```
homepage_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Password Safe"')))
```

4. another xpath with text

```
homepage_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
'/div/h2[contains(text(),"Password Safe")]')))
```

5. full css - a little verbose to reproduce here

I have also looked at the posts here: [Locate an element in selenium using text inside h2 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112185/locate-an-element-in-selenium-using-text-inside-h2-tag)
and nothing there works for me. I just need to locate it and click on it.

Here is something simpler that may be easier to diagnose.
[image: screenshot]I click to a page which I have attached a screenshot of above. It has an app bar across the top as you can see. On top right is a menu that has "Requests" in text on a clickable element. When my app clicks on it, the app-bar now shows "Accounts" where it showed "Requests" before. I am unable to detect any other change in the app-bar. I have a time.sleep(5) and a wait-until-page-loads after clicking on "Requests". When I watch the html source code change with this click, all that seems to happen (within the context of the app-bar) is that the text "Requests" is now instructed to change to "Accounts". See html source code below.

I am able to locate the "Requests" element perfectly using this:

```
requests_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'app-bar-quicklinks > ul > li:nth-child(1)')))
```

When app-bar changes to "Accounts", CSS for the element seems to be identical to the one I use above for "Requests". Yet, it times out. How come?

```
<app-bar-quicklinks class="ng-isolate-scope" style="opacity: 1;">
    <ul class="flex-x h-start v-center">
        <!-- ngRepeat: link in qlinks.service.list track by $index -->
        <li ng-repeat="link in qlinks.service.list track by $index" ng-click="qlinks.navTo($index)" ng-keydown="qlinks.navTo($index, $event)" tabindex="0" class="flex-x h-end v-center ng-binding ng-scope">Requests
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: link in qlinks.service.list track by $index --> .       
        <li ng-repeat="link in qlinks.service.list track by $index" ng-click="qlinks.navTo($index)" ng-keydown="qlinks.navTo($index, $event)" tabindex="-1" class="flex-x h-end v-center ng-binding ng-scope">Admin Sessions
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: link in qlinks.service.list track by $index -->
    </ul>
</app-bar-quicklinks>
```

Comment: If the HTML you posted is correct, #2 should have worked. Are you sure it's not in an `IFRAME`? Have you tried to wait for visible and not clickable? Maybe something weird is going on there.

Comment: @JeffC: Its definitely not in an iframe. But it might be hidden. I tried waiting for visible with same result.

Comment: I don't suppose you can post a link to the page?

Comment: I am afraid not. I can share a screenshot of the html/webpage so you can see sections. Pasting all of it is going to be overkill.

Comment: Are you sure the wait time is enough? Have you tried adding a breakpoint and letting the page fully load and then continuing the script? It may be that the page is taking longer than expected to fully load.

Comment: I use time.sleep(5) followed by wait-until-page-loads after any click. Please see updates to my post above for a related issue and possibly easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to a frame after clicking on 'Requests' and needed to switch out of it to find the 'Accounts' link. Resolved now.